# Cannot implicitly convert child class to parent class in type parametrized method

Tags: c#, generics, language-design

I recently had to help troubleshoot an issue someone had with returning from a generic method, and while there were multiple problems to be solved, I understood and could explain all of them - except for the last hurdle of getting the compiler to accept the return type. Though I eventually succeeded in getting the program to compile and run correctly, I still can't completely follow the logic of *why* it had to be done this way.

I've reproduced the issue with a minimal example below. Given a very simple parent-child class structure with only a single generic method:

```
abstract class AbstractParentClass
{
    public abstract T DoThing<T>() where T : AbstractParentClass;
}

class ConcreteChildClass : AbstractParentClass
{
    public override T DoThing<T>()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This will cause an error on the return line of `Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConcreteChildClass' to 'T'`. Slightly strange given that `T` is constrained to be an instance of `AbstractParentClass` and `this` trivially is one of those but okay, sure, so we'll do it explicitly:

```
public override T DoThing<T>()
{
    return (T) this;
}
```

Now the error message reads `Cannot convert type 'ConcreteChildClass' to 'T'`. What? If `T` were unconstrained then sure, I get that we couldn't guarantee it, but with an inheritance like we do, surely it should be a straightforward cast?

We can get close by explicitly casting to the parent class:

```
public override T DoThing<T>()
{
    return (AbstractParentClass) this;
}
```

Now the error reads `Cannot implicitly convert type 'AbstractParentClass' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. Why can we not implicitly convert to the exact type of the constraint - what possible situation could lead to a class of the constraint type to not be convertable to... itself? But at least this is solvable now, the error message even tells us directly how to do it:

```
public override T DoThing<T>()
{
    return (T)(AbstractParentClass) this;
}
```

And now everything runs just fine. We can even make it look slightly prettier if we want:

```
public override T DoThing<T>()
{
    return this as T;
}
```

Throughout all of this, if `T` were unconstrained, I of course understand why these conversions wouldn't be possible as written. But it is, and in a way that the compiler should not have any issue following. Does the compiler, for some reason, just not take type constraints into account for allowable implicit conversions? In my experience all situations like this in C# have a very good reason behind them, I just for the life of me can't figure it out for this one.

If anybody has any insight into why the compiler has trouble with this (seemingly!) very simple bit of code, I'd be thankful for an explanation of the problems with allowing these conversions.

Comment: I thought for sure you had to have been missing something, but you're absolutely right. T is being properly constrained in `ConcreteChildClass`. However, can you provide the real world example of why you need this to work so that we can make sure it's not an X/Y problem? Using `public abstract AbstractParentClass DoThing();` is functionally no different from your example, and it works.

Comment: I don't know the full real world use case myself, having only helped debug this issue via Discord. However, skipping the type parameters wouldn't be an option here because the returned type needs to be the specific subclass that `DoThing()` is being called on, and using a covariant return type is not possible since the project is still in C#7. (I suppose you could return `AbstractParentClass` and then cast the returned value to the specific subclass, but that doesn't make it feel any better if I'm honest).

I'm only interested in the reasoning behind this compiler behavior!

Comment: Ah okay. I agree that casting back from a the parent class is just as bad if not worse than your approach. Fun fact, using an interface instead, even with an explicit interface call in the child class, you encounter the exact same errors.

Comment: "the returned type needs to be the specific subclass that `DoThing()` is being called on" No it doesn't... It only needs to be a type that inherits `AbstractParentClass`

Comment: I phrased that badly; it doesn't need to be by language constraints, but it needs to be in terms of intent for the method, so that you can use methods from `ConcreteChildClass` on the returned object which are not in `AbstractParentClass` (without manually casting the returned object which, as noted above, is just terrible from a usability standpoint).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becasue technically you could do:

```
class ConcreteChildClass2 : AbstractParentClass
{
    public override T DoThing<T>()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

var ccc = new ConcreteChildClass();
var ccc2 = ccc.DoThing<ConcreteChildClass2>();
```

Even with the casts you do, this will blow up at runtime:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteChildClass' to type 'ConcreteChildClass2'.
```

If instead you do `return this as T`, you'll get `null` as a result instead of a casting exception.

In other words, the constraint does not guarantee that `DoThing` returns the same type as the defining class, it only guarantees that it returns some type that inherits  `AbstractParentClass`.

Comment: This does of course make sense as to why you can't just cast `ConcreteChildClass` to `T` directly! Then I'd just like to know if we can figure out why it can't implicitly cast `AbstractParentClass` to `T` either (in the second example), that's the really weird part to me...

Comment: Because not every `AbstractParentClass` is a `T`. When you cast you tell the compiler to "trust" that you know that the instance is a T. If you're wrong, you'll get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Comment: Given the `where T : AbstractParentClass` constraint though, it should be the case that the cast is always possible, unless I'm misunderstanding something fundamental? Without the constraint it obviously wouldn't be possible to make that assumption, yes.

Comment: Look at my first example. In that case `this` is a `ConcreteChildClass` but `T` is `ConcreteChildClass2`, so it would try to cast a `ConcreteChildClass` to a `ConcreteChildClass2` which would fail.

Comment: Ah, right, because it would be trying to narrow it back down to a different child class instead of returning as the parent class, of course. Thanks, I think I finally got rid of that block in my logic, that all makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

The "why" is that even though `ConcreteChildClass` is an `AbstractParentClass` and `T` is an `AbstractParentClass`, that does not necessarily guarantee that `ConcreteChildClass` is a `T`.

For a real-world analogy, `Cat` is a `Pet` and `Dog` is a `Pet`, but `Cat` is not a `Dog`.

D Stanley's answer shows how you could invoke `DoThing()` with a value for `T` that wouldn't be correct for the type of object you're dealing with.

Depending on your use case, there are some other patterns you could try using to solve this problem.

For example, you could use a recursive enum declaration type on your parent class, similar to what Java does for its Enums:

```
abstract class AbstractParentClass<T> where T : AbstractParentClass<T>
{
    public abstract T DoThing();
}

class ConcreteChildClass : AbstractParentClass<ConcreteChildClass>
{
    public override ConcreteChildClass DoThing()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This makes it so you can't tell a `ConcreteChildClass` to use a different class as its generic type when you invoke DoThing(). You enforce that any child class that follows the pattern correctly must return an instance of the right type. However, it forces you to propagate the generic type everywhere: you can't just refer to an `AbstractParentClass` without including some generic parameter. You can get around that with a non-generic interface for code to use it doesn't care which implementation type it's given. But it's still a little clunky because (unlike Java Enums) you can't really enforce that every implementation extends the parent class *and* uses itself as the generic type.

Comment: But you could do `class ConcreteChildClass2: AbstractParentClass<ConcreteChildClass>`. Not sure what harm/benefit that would be but it still does not guarantee that the generic method returns an instance of the defining class.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant in my final sentence.

Comment: The main advantage to the example I gave would come if the people extending the base class are likely to be more closely tied to (and conscientious of) the rules to follow than the people invoking the methods. For example, if you're writing a library where you'll be providing the implementations of the various classes extending the parent class, and you're expecting consumers of the library to be calling `DoThing` on those instances, the compiler won't keep you from messing up, but at least it can keep the consumers of your library from providing the wrong generic type in their method call.